# pgfplotstable error: missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: errors, pgfplotstable

I'm getting strange errors with `pgfplotstable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypesetfile[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}
\end{document}
```

And the `n.csv` file:

```
lambda,n
6907.16,1.4190
6716.17,1.4185
5790.65,1.4252
5769.59,1.4256
5460.74,1.4272
4916.04,1.4345
4358.35,1.4412
4347.50,1.4461
4339.24,1.4475
4077.81,1.4555
4046.56,1.4572
```

What's wrong with it:

```
 Missing \endcsname inserted. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Extra \endcsname. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Missing \endcsname inserted. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Extra \endcsname. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Missing \endcsname inserted. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Extra \endcsname. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
Undefined control sequence. [...le[columns={lambda,n},col sep=comma]{n.csv}]
```

Comment: Your code works without error for me. It looks like you have some mis-encoded control characters. Try cutting the example back off the website into a clean file and see if you get errors then.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I copy-and-paste the code and it works. Strange errors...

Comment: If you diff with your original you may see where the different characters are, should we close this as too localised?